# sql- get data from one table to insert into another in a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a trigger and I need to insert the ID from the tracks able into the events table AFTER insert into tracks. I just need to select the ID from tracks, nothing more. The ID in the tracks table has a foreign key to the ID in another table named members. I doubt that is important but just in case. I shouldn't imagine you need any info on the tables but just ask if you do.

Here is my trigger

```
 delimiter $$

   CREATE

   TRIGGER tracks_event AFTER INSERT
   ON tracks FOR EACH ROW 

     BEGIN

        INSERT into events(ID, action)
        VALUES (?, has uploaded a track.);

    END$$

delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the ID that is in the tracks row being inserted then you can use `NEW.ID`. This will give you this ID column of the row that has been inserted.

For more trigger examples and a few hints the MySQL reference manual helps (along with being a great reference for syntax etc):
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html